# Шаблоны, явная специализация с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int size,class T> T min(T* a)
{
    T m=a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(a[i]<m) m=a[i];
    return m;
}

template<int si,char*>
char* min(char**a)      
{                           
    char*m=a[0];            
    for(int i=0;i<si;i++)   
        if(strcmp(a[i],m)<0) m=a[i];
    return m;
}
```

что это такое? это ведь и не специализация, и не перегрузка шаблона... тогда что?
прост как я понял, специализация всегда начинается с `template<>`

но когда я пишу так:

```
template<>char* min<int si,char*>(char**a){/*тот же код*/},
```

то подчёркивает, хотя, как я понял, синтаксис специализации именно такой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это перегрузка. У вас есть, таким образом, *два* шаблона функции.

Специализация не сработала, поскольку вы хотели *частичную* специализацию (специализировать `T`, но не `size`). НО частичная специализация шаблонов функций не разрешена.

---

Насколько я понимаю, у вас ещё одна ошибка: во втором случае параметр-тип *не нужен*, поэтому должно быть так:

```
template<int size>
char* min(char** a)
{
    char* m = a[0];
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        if (strcmp(a[i], m) < 0) m = a[i];
    return m;
}
```

http://ideone.com/EVNOV2

---

Обратите внимание, что у вас числовой параметр шаблона не выводится из использования, поэтому его всегда необходимо будет указывать вручную. Это не очень удобно, гораздо лучше заставить машину работать за вас:

```
template<int size, class T>
T min2(const T (&a)[size])
{
    T m = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(a[i] < m) m = a[i];
    return m;
}
```

http://ideone.com/3UKXia

В этом случае вам *не надо* указывать размер вручную, компилятор всё сделает за вас.